# bind before connect at client code

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I have multiple ethernet I/Fs. eth0,eth1,eth2... and I want to connect to an external server, eg 1.2.3.4:80.

My connections are OK, but under some special circumstances I want to connect as eth1 and not eth0. the server's code checks the IP address of my interface. I think that I need to bind before connect. Without bind(2) the server always gets packets from eth0

I am looking for code that demonstrates this behavior. Does anybody has a link to an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need `bind(2)` for this.

What you're looking to do here is to use a different *network interface* with your socket.  To use a network interface other than the system default, you need to use the `SO_BINDTODEVICE` socket option along with `setsockopt`.  The interface you want to use, such as `"eth1"` for example, should be specified as a string in the `ifr_name` field of a [`ifreq` struct](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl7_netdevice.htm) which is to be passed to `setsockopt`.  To do this, you need to include the `<net/if.h>` header.

Basically, something like the following (untested) code:

```
int set_interface(int socket_fd, const char* interface_name)
{
    ifreq interface;
    memset(&interface, 0, sizeof(interface));
    strncpy(interface.ifr_name, interface_name, IFNAMSIZ);
    int res = setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &ifreq, sizeof(ifreq));
    return res;
}
```

Also, make sure you check the return code, in case `setsockopt` fails.

Comment: what is the difference between bind and SO_BINDTODEVICE? why bind does not solve the problem in my case?

Comment: @cateof, `bind(2)` binds a socket to a particular endpoint (IP address and port.)  It has no notion of "network interfaces".  To associate a socket with a certain network interface, you need to use special facilities from the `<net/if.h>` header.