# is it possible sending data via NIC directly instead of via routing table lookup (linux command or python)

Tags: python, linux, sockets, iptables

Suppose I have 3 NIC in one host PC, name them eth0, eth1 and eth2

All interface have it's own ip address in different subnet, however, all the gateway router of those NIC have route to one server I want to access, I want to establish 3 connetions to that server and get response via different NIC.

I setting static route with different metric in that host PC, which means all ethX have route to server.

Is it possible establish tcp sessions via different NIC directly in python or via shell command sorts of:

```
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s1.connect((HOST, PORT, eth1))         # eth1 is my fiction
# and in same program  
s0 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s0.connect((HOST, PORT, eth0))         # ethO is my fiction
```

then the traffic can be send to that eth directly intead of via routing table lookup?

Thank!

Comment: possible duplicate of [bind before connect at client code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404572/bind-before-connect-at-client-code). The answer is in C, but should be easily translated to Python.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, in this case SO_BINDTODEVICE is not sufficient since that does not provide the address of the gateway router on each subnet

Comment: @user478514, does the host you're connecting to have multiple IP addresses?

Comment: How about binding one socket to the ip-address of one NIC?

Comment: "I want to establish 3 connetions to that server and get response via different NIC."  Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Brian Cain, some kind of applicaiton instance load balance due to bad app design.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that routing is determined by the destination and just because you have multiple routes available, doesn't mean that the OS will in fact use those multiple routes.  What you want is the OS to take into account the source address when determining which outbound route to use.  Once you get the routing correct, you can bind the source IP address on your socket and it will don the right thing.

In linux, you do this by creating multiple routing tables and setting up rules for picking those routing tables based on source IP address.  In general, the documentation for this is pretty bad, but searching for "multiple default routes" and iproute2 can help narrow it down.  Here are a couple of reasonable pages:
http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/377
http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

OpenBSD also has support for multiple routing tables and I find it a bit easier to configure without hacking stuff into init scripts.  (You can even just do it in pf.conf)