# Avoid data being sent through interface not matching address

Tags: c, linux, macos, sockets, freebsd

Imagine a network setup like this:

```
+---------+               +---------+                     
|      (1)+---------------+(2)      |    
|  host1  |               |  host2  |
|         |               |         |
|      (3)+---------------+(4)      |
+---------+               +---------+
```

where 1,2,3,4 are network interfaces. A line between two interfaces means there is a (routed) connection. Now when I setup a client and a server, bind the server to the IP address of 4 and the client to 1 I am still able to establish a connection since outgoing traffic of host1 will be routed through interface 3.

The following code is not my actual program but example code taken from [a tutorial](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm). I slightly modified it. It is solely used to show some working code that does not behave like I want it to behave.

server.c

```
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     inet_aton(argv[2], &serv_addr.sin_addr);
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");
     bzero(buffer,256);
     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
     n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, client_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_aton(argv[3], &client_addr.sin_addr);
    client_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr,
              sizeof(client_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

What I want is that traffic only flows from 1 to 2 (or vice versa) and from 3 to 4 (or vice versa). Ideally trying to establish a connection from e.g. 1 to 4 should fail because there is no route.

I cannot modify the routing table of any host (or is it possible to change it only for my process?).
I already tried [SO_BINDTODEVICE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404572/bind-before-connect-at-client-code). In general this does what I want, namely traffic is then flowing through 1 and 4. It does, however, not avoid a connection between 1 and 4 being established. The later is not a requirement but would be nice to have. Unfortunately, SO_BINDTODEVICE is not available on OSX and I could not find any similar socket option.

```
int bind_to_if(int fd, const char * const if_name)
{
  struct ifreq interface;

  memset(&interface, 0, sizeof(interface));
  strncpy(interface.ifr_name, if_name, IFNAMSIZ);
  if(setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &interface, sizeof(struct ifreq))) {
    return -1;
  }

  return0;
}
```

My code needs to run under Linux, FreeBSD and OSX. Some ifdefs would be acceptable if they cannot be avoided.

Comment: To whom down-voted this and/or voted this as being off topic. Could you please explain why you think so? I don't see why this should not be programming related since obviously I am looking for a way to modify my program to archive the described. Any suggestions to improve the questions are welcome

Comment: Can you clarify if `SO_BINDTODEVICE` does what you want ? *This does not avoid a connection between 1 and 4 being established but traffic is flowing through 1 and 4 as I want it* is unclear.

Comment: @cnicutar Thanks, I tried to clarify it. `SO_BINDTODEVICE` forces traffic to flow through the desired interfaces (what is a strong requirement) but it does not avoid a connection being established between e.g. 1 and 4 (what is not a requirement but would be nice to have).

Comment: Try setting `SO_DONTROUTE` in addition to `SO_BINDTODEVICE` ?

Comment: [Here](https://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2005/May/msg00073.html) it is said that SO_DONTROUTE really means no routing. That means if 1 and 2 are not in the same subnet no connection could be established either.

Comment: Why not aggregate both links into one?